# PEERING connectivity issues between VPC's?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering, peering

Could you help me with the network infrastructure below reference "PEERING" ?

We have in GCP Cloud 2(two) VPC

The First - "vpc-shared-nonprod"
Projetc Name: "Shared"
Subnet Name: subnet-shared-nonprod "10.1.0.0/24"

The Second "vpc-4i-shared-prod"
Projetc Name: "Shared"
Subnet Name: subnet-shared-prod "10.2.0.0/24"

We are not able to create PEERING between the Projects "vpc-shared-nonprod" "Shared - 10.1.0.0/24" and "vpc-shared-prod" "Shared - 10.2.0.0/24"

Comment: Dear, Alejandro

Comment: Dear, Alejandro

No! I need to connect two project that are in diferents(environments QA and PRD) VPC and I'm not able to use peering between VPCs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what error you are getting?

My understanding is that you are trying to use Shared VPC, is that correct?
If so, [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#setting_up) is a nice step by step of how to achieve that.